# database error invalid values

Tags: mysql, database

i am getting error in my database. i am encountering invalid default value for `timestamp`. how can i fix this.

here's my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `thread` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `view` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `profileUrl` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'https://mymonas.com/forum/img/nophoto.png',
  `profileBg` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `aboutMe` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `isModerator` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're running MySQL 5.5. If that's the case, you can't use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with DATETIME. DATETIME has to have a default of null or no default value. You can, however, change them to TIMESTAMP, but then you can only have one default and one ON UPDATE per table. You can also use a post-insert trigger to fill in a NOW() value on new records. [Here's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) the docs to help.

Answer (score 0):

use TIMESTAMP instead of datetime
[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Hi thanks can you rewrote my database the table above. i am new in programming

Comment: excecute ALTER TABLE `thread` CHANGE `dateCreated` `dateCreated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;